# Culebra can't find pillow

Tags: pip, python-imaging-library

Attempting to use `culebra -G` on my macbook.

When I attempt to do this, it tells me to install `pillow`.

The problem is, pillow is installed.

```
Python 3.9.6 (default, Mar 10 2023, 20:16:38) 
[Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PIL
```

I am able to import PIL without any issue. I have installed it using pip in my venv.

How can I fix this or diagnose the issue?